# imagepath changes to null when not updated in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Here is my code :

```
<div class="col-sm-4 pl-5">
  <img attr.src="{{item?.imagePath}}"  required height="200" width="200">
</div>
```

Ts File :

```
editBlog() {
console.log(this.teamForm.value)
const BlogPost =     {

  "firstName": this.teamForm.value.firstName,
  "lastName": this.teamForm.value.lastName,
  "description": this.teamForm.value.description,
  "designation": this.teamForm.value.designation,
  "imagePath": this.teamForm.controls['imagePath'].value,
  "status": "status",
  "active": true,
  "employmentType": {
      "id": this.type,
      // "employmentTypeName": "Full-Time"
  }
}
console.log(BlogPost)
console.log('hftttttt',this.teamForm.value.imagePath)
// console.log(this.id,this.item,this.employmentType)
if(window.confirm('Are you sure you want to update?')){
const jsonData= BlogPost;
if(this.file['name']){}
const formData = new FormData()
formData.append('file', this.file , this.file['name']); 
formData.append('jsonData', JSON.stringify(jsonData));
this.team.editTeam(this.id,formData).subscribe((response)=> {
  this.router.navigate(['/home/team'])
  console.log(response);
});
```

Here an empty(null) call is generated to API when image is not updated,How to eliminate this and how to push the old imagePath if i am not updating the values to the element?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can directly call the image path to typescript file using the html tag id,

Typescript file

```
"imagePath": (<HTMLInputElement>document.getElementById("imagePath")).src),
```

Html

```
<img attr.src="{{item?.imagePath}}" id="imagePath" required height="200" width="200">
```